Who does "they’ve” refer to in "Can you get the name of the scientist they've called?"?
Strauss (Robert Downy Jr) is having a conversation
with a Senate Aide. In this discussion, Strauss mentions that he is easy to
blame for what happened to Oppenheimer (Cilian Murphy) and that the scientific
community doesn’t support him.
Later in the conversation, Strauss asks the Senate Aide to get the name
of a scientist that “they’ve” called. Here is the exact dialogue:

STRAUSS:  Can you get the name of the scientist they've called?
SENATE AIDE: Probably.

In this scene, I’m unsure who “they’ve” refers to.
Who does “they’ve” refer to?

They are discussing witnesses to the Senate Security Committee, so "they" refers to the Senate Committee referred to as the "Security Board" in the movie that Strauss is testifying to.

The Senate's standing committees system began in 1816. Prior to that time, the Senate relied on temporary select committees. Three types of committees have evolved through the years: standing, select/special, and joint. Members receive committee assignments through their party conferences. As "little legislatures," committees monitor governmental operations, review legislation, provide oversight, and recommend courses of action to the full Senate.

Source: senate.gov
